# Laravel 5.3 multiple ignore rules for one non-key field

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I use soft deletes which I then ignore/exlude in the validation rules in Laravel 5.3.

How do I enforce two ignores in a validation array for updates?

```
 'number'      => "required|unique:customers,number,NULL,id,company_id,
                       $company_id},deleted_at,NULL",
```

I need to add the exclusion of the current record as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. For your information(field = number) :

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            'number'       => "required|unique:customers,number,{$id},id,company_id,{$company_id},deleted_at,NULL",
            'name'         => 'required',
            'street'       => 'required',
            'streetnumber' => 'required',
            'zipcode'      => 'required',
            'city'         => 'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: Starting from `company_id`, they will be set of **column name** and **ignore value**. I took 4~6 hours to find this answer :(((